# bestglm : Error in levels(x)[x] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts

Tags: r, glm

was trying to use bestglm function via the AIC method to come up with a logistic regression model. 
The following is a summary of the data set I ran it on:
[dataset summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LINpf.png)

The following is the line I ran:

```
best1 <- bestglm(trainset, IC="AIC", family=binomial)
```

The following is the error message I have received:

```
Error in levels(x)[x] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : ‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

> dput(testset)
>   structure(list(EyeContact = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
>   1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>   2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), Post.Processing = structure(c(2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>   1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>   2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
>       HairColour = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 
>       1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>       2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
>       2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
>       4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
>       1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("BL", "BR", "NULL", "O"), class = "factor"), 
>       Animals = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
>       Age = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("21", "22", "23"), class = "factor"), 
>       Backview = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
>       SkinTone = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
>       2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>       2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Dark", "Fair", "NULL"), class = "factor"), 
>       Smile = structure(c(5L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 
>       4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
>       3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 
>       5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
>       4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
>       5L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 
>       4L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
>       5L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("CS", "NS", "NULL", "O", "ST"), class = "factor"), 
>       HairLength = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
>       1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
>       1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>       2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("L", "NULL", "SM"), class = "factor"), 
>       HairTexture = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
>       3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 
>       1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
>       3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
>       1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
>       1L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
>       1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("C", "NULL", "S"), class = "factor"), 
>       HairStyle = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("LD", "NULL", "T"), class = "factor"), 
>       Outfit = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 
>       4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
>       2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       2L, 4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("D", "I", "NULL", "O"), class = "factor"), 
>       Background = structure(c(2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
>       1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 
>       1L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("I", "N", "NULL", "P"), class = "factor"), 
>       TypeofShot = structure(c(1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
>       4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>       1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
>       4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
>       2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
>       3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
>       2L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("CU", "ECU", "LS", "MS"), class = "factor"), 
>       Obstruction = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
>       1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
>       1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "NULL", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
>       Makeup = structure(c(4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
>       2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 
>       4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 
>       4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
>       3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
>       1L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
>       1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("H", "L", "N", "NULL"), class = "factor"), 
>       Results = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
>       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
>       prediction = c(9.32475933917106e-09, 0.0385259384817495, 
>       0.0678681154072461, 0.234968717458685, 0.0290199853775816, 
>       0.171162293958793, 0.00129264601900783, 0.00675484440459677, 
>       0.128155946032347, 0.133539709174044, 0.118744423809008, 
>       0.060206929901843, 0.128155946032347, 0.146426608321148, 
>       0.0552623520735392, 0.227991153820736, 2.54581077993876e-08, 
>       0.0195543511193415, 0.128155946032347, 0.256310568145846, 
>       0.0520386124569491, 0.111383163512112, 0.0402597164944323, 
>       0.0141022328039524, 0.55471858422641, 0.128155946032347, 
>       0.35526622136263, 0.128155946032347, 0.382743622548627, 0.00485338573377989, 
>       0.128155946032347, 0.0324058895421302, 0.320728574893713, 
>       0.320728574893713, 0.35526622136263, 0.146426608321148, 0.0179540767871002, 
>       0.398798221640772, 0.362407391381727, 0.00485338573377989, 
>       0.00129264601900783, 0.128155946032347, 0.0823507208338033, 
>       0.00675484440459677, 0.0195543511193415, 0.320728574893713, 
>       0.128155946032347, 0.174534177022049, 0.0477307982973154, 
>       0.0625662879441275, 0.0174929064796301, 0.135882446473831, 
>       0.00696631574219797, 0.419831884479578, 0.0862150002573959, 
>       0.128155946032347, 0.0698582713166507, 0.128155946032347, 
>       0.174534177022049, 0.146426608321148, 0.0234463612462439, 
>       0.0141022328039524, 0.0239924885903984, 0.0290199853775816, 
>       3.15391485574326e-09, 1.14002192545012e-08, 0.0345251778805331, 
>       0.208346726243955, 0.0203551415502053, 0.020830802150735, 
>       0.128155946032347, 0.197915823620481, 0.146426608321148, 
>       9.32475933917106e-09, 9.32475933917106e-09, 0.128155946032347, 
>       0.0552623520735392, 0.016802787713206, 0.0345251778805331, 
>       0.146426608321148, 0.00675484440459677, 0.00579370288906212, 
>       0.320728574893713, 0.00316694181006374, 0.320728574893713, 
>       0.146426608321148, 1.66951123737628e-08, 0.0466701670833381, 
>       0.0402597164944323, 0.382743622548627, 0.128155946032347, 
>       0.128155946032347, 0.118744423809008, 0.171162293958793, 
>       0.0402597164944323, 0.146426608321148, 0.0895467055067367, 
>       0.0110101302622226, 0.05872534886842, 0.35526622136263, 0.0141022328039524, 
>       0.118744423809008, 0.00414031965843898)), .Names = c("EyeContact", 
>   "Post.Processing", "HairColour", "Animals", "Age", "Backview", 
>   "SkinTone", "Smile", "HairLength", "HairTexture", "HairStyle", 
>   "Outfit", "Background", "TypeofShot", "Obstruction", "Makeup", 
>   "Results", "prediction"), row.names = c(2L, 3L, 9L, 17L, 19L, 
>   22L, 23L, 28L, 29L, 41L, 42L, 45L, 47L, 53L, 55L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
>   72L, 78L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 90L, 94L, 95L, 101L, 103L, 
>   106L, 111L, 113L, 116L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 122L, 123L, 128L, 130L, 
>   134L, 136L, 138L, 144L, 146L, 148L, 150L, 152L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 
>   165L, 168L, 174L, 175L, 180L, 181L, 183L, 194L, 204L, 207L, 210L, 
>   213L, 214L, 215L, 221L, 224L, 230L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 239L, 
>   240L, 244L, 249L, 250L, 255L, 259L, 262L, 272L, 277L, 278L, 280L, 
>   281L, 284L, 289L, 296L, 297L, 304L, 306L, 308L, 316L, 321L, 323L, 
>   327L, 329L, 332L, 335L, 337L, 339L, 340L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: We would need your dataset to help you. Could you use dput or the like ?

Comment: @Cedric thank you so much for your help!

Comment: It seems that you have "NULL" as factor levels in your dataset. `>levels(trainset$HairColour) 
[1] "BL"   "BR"   "NULL" "O"   `Is that intended ?

Comment: @Cedric yes it is. Thank you so much for your prompt replies :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model is running, it gives some output but the print method doesn't work.

```
> print(best1)
AIC
Best Model:
Error in levels(x)[x] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In model.response(mf, "numeric") :
  using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored
2: In Ops.factor(y, z$residuals) : '-' not meaningful for factors
```

but best1 structure is correct and best1$BestModel is provided

```
best1$BestModel

Call:  glm(formula = y ~ ., family = family, data = Xi, weights = weights)

Coefficients:
     (Intercept)  Post.ProcessingY             Age22             Age23  
         -40.416          -244.338            59.277           -41.652  
    SkinToneFair      SkinToneNULL           SmileNS         SmileNULL  
         245.316            -5.102           -80.986          -142.908  
          SmileO           SmileST    HairLengthNULL      HairLengthSM  
        -121.258           -80.482          -159.677           -20.045  
         OutfitI        OutfitNULL           OutfitO       BackgroundN  
          41.652           -41.653          -410.492            19.895  
  BackgroundNULL       BackgroundP     TypeofShotECU      TypeofShotLS  
         -82.640          -208.283            16.369          -101.467  
    TypeofShotMS           MakeupL           MakeupN        MakeupNULL  
         101.819            39.438          -122.850           285.187  

Degrees of Freedom: 102 Total (i.e. Null);  79 Residual
Null Deviance:      69.99 
Residual Deviance: 5.545    AIC: 53.55
```

You could replace the print.bestglm method with

```
print.bestglm <- function (x, ...) 
{
  ti <- x$Title
  cat(ti, fill = TRUE)
  if ((x$ModelReport$Bestk > 0) || (x$ModelReport$IncludeInterceptQ)) {
    cat("Best Model:", fill = TRUE)
    if (any(x$ModelReport$NumDF > 1)) 
      out <- summary(x$BestModel)
    else out <- summary(x$BestModel)$coefficients
    print(out)
  }
  else cat("Best Model is the null model with no parameters.", 
        fill = TRUE)
}
```

The problem is that the code uses a deprecated feature. It calls aov on a glm object, which is wrong. I think that using the replacement function should solve the problem.

Comment: sorry I might not have rearranged the columns appropriately. If my last column is Results, does it work?

if not, do you know why?

Comment: Yes, took me some time to run through all the function while in fact it was just at the end that the print method was not working, see my post. Hope this helps you.